# Woocommerce and PayPal Here integration

Tags: paypal, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm interested to see if anybody is looking to integrate Woocommerce with the PayPal Here payment App? More so the importing of products from Woocommerce to the PayPal Here App. Be a great addition.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked into that specifically, but I will be adding a "virtual terminal" / POS functionality into my [PayPal for WooCommerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) plugin before long.  I've got it planned for the next full version release.

It basically gives you a section in the WP admin panel where site owners can easily put together invoices using their WooCommerce inventory and then process those orders accordingly.  I will be including the Invoicing API's so you can create an invoice from the Woo VT order page, or you'll also have the ability to swipe a card using a [USBSwiper card reader](http://www.usbswiper.com/usbswiper-usb-magnetic-stripe-credit-card-reader.html).  Of course, you could also key in card data if you needed to do it that way.

The cool thing about that is even when you key in the transactions you still get your 2.2% - 2.9% rate depending on your volume because it would be processed over Payments Pro in that case.  Same with invoicing or swiping.

Back to your original question, though, I'm unaware of any API or tool that allows us to interact directly with the Here inventory.  They do have the Sideloader API for PayPal Here, which would allow you to send inventory (or a specific order) into the Here app from your own app in order to complete an order, but I don't think it lets you push inventory directly into the actual Here app.

On that note, what I could potentially do is build a stand-alone app that does nothing but pull in current WooCommerce inventory, and then from there you could create orders through the Sideloader API using that inventory, but it would use the Here app to actually complete the order.  Seems a little clunky, but in theory, that should work fine.

If you want to [contact me directly](http://www.angelleye.com/contact-us) we could discuss getting this done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Right at this time PayPal Here is designed to be card present, so you cannot import your products from Woocomerce into the PayPal Here App.

Here is a link to an FAQ on PayPal Here:

[PayPal Here FAQ](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/credit-card-reader-faq?mid=hSPJmczs;2315893772;paypal%20here;p;;eu84e2fpi0&mpch=ads&mplx=3484-158110-27959-0)

Here is the current list of PayPal Here Partners:

[PayPal Here Partners](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/accept-payments-in-store)